# loading local storage in one read

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have several items that I'm storing in the local storage. What the page loads, I have about 20 lines like this:

```
 var SomeVar = localStorage.getItem('SomeKey');
```

I'd like to change this and get all the storage data in one read, store it in a temporary object, and get the 20 variables from that temporary object.

How can I read local storage in one read?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a reason you'd want to do this, but you could take advantage of the fact that `localStorage` is basically an object and do something like this:

```
var tempLocalStorage = {};
for(prop in localStorage) {
    if(localStorage.hasOwnProp(prop)) {
        tempLocalStorage[prop] = localStorage.getItem(prop);
    }
}

var SomeVar = tempLocalStorage["SomeKey"];
```

I'm looping through the values in `localStorage` and adding them to a temporary local storage variable. Then you can access the temporary local storage variable with the same keys as you would standard `localStorage`, but with standard object property syntax, not the custom `getItem()` syntax that `localStorage` uses.

---

**Edit**: Here's a suggestion. Save all your variables to one object, then load and save that object from and to `localStorage` instead of saving seperate objects. It's the individual variable accessing calls that take the most time. It takes roughly the same amount of time to read 10 characters from a single variable into memory that it does reading 1000, according to [this post](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2011/localstorage-read-performance/) on `localStorage` optimization.

Comment: because each time you're accessing a property, you're accessing it from the hard drive. I want to get everything from the hard drive in one read instead of 20.

Comment: @frenchie: That's true, but if you're only reading 20 variables I don't think that would cause any performance issues, if that's what you're worried about. I'd be worried if I were getting hundreds or thousands of variables instead.

Comment: I know it'd be a minimal optimization; I was wondering if it'd be possible. No biggie if not.

Comment: @frenchie: Well, I'd be careful about premature optimization, but you can see my updated answer for one way of squeezing a little more speed out of your `localStorage` calls. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could keep all your variables in a single object and use JSON to convert it to and from a string:

```
// read:
var localvars = JSON.parse(localStorage.myvars || '{}');
// copy from temporary object to desired variable:
var someVar = localvars.someKey;
// write:
localStorage.myvars = JSON.stringify(localvars);
```

If you use this method you would have to be careful not to store any recursive variables in `localvars`, as that would cause `JSON.stringify` to fail. But that isn't really a problem because you wouldn't have been able to store those structures in `localStorage` anyway.

I wouldn't recommend using a for-in loop on localStorage because you should not assume your script is the only one accessing `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at jStorage? http://www.jstorage.info/  I use it quite a bit and it seems to do something similar in that it stores everything under one object.  Also cross-browser for older IE versions.